# Absolute Value Inequality Domain Restrictions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm almost embarrassed to post this elementary question, but I beg your indulgence.

For the inequality $$-3 \left| x-4 \right| +2 > 6 + 2x$$

[a graphical examination](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jeox31dc0s) immediately shows no solutions. However, solving this algebraically shows a solution that is the union of two intervals.

For the sake of completeness, I'll walk through it, though I will limit comments.
$$-3 \left| x-4 \right| > 4 + 2x$$
$$ \left| x-4 \right| < \frac{4+2x}{-3}$$
Which yields two inequalities
$$ +\left( x-4 \right) < \frac{4+2x}{-3}$$
and
$$ -\left( x-4 \right) < \frac{4+2x}{-3}$$
Solving the first
$$  x-4 < \frac{4+2x}{-3}$$
$$  -3x+12 > 4+2x$$
$$  8 > 5x$$
$$ x<\frac{8}{5}$$
And the second
$$  -x+4 < \frac{4+2x}{-3}$$
$$  3x-12 > 4+2x$$
$$  x > 16$$
so our algebraic solution is $x<\frac{8}{5}$ OR $  x > 16$. But this is obviously false based on the graph. Is there an absolute value domain restriction somewhere I'm missing?

Comment: It is not or, it is AND! If we have $|x|<1$ then $x<1$ and $x>-1$, not or.

Comment: Agreed! $\left|x-4 \right| < \frac{4+2x}{-3}$ is definitely an AND situation - but tell me where the algebra is lacking?

Comment: There is no lack. Since $x<8/5$ and $x>16$ there is no solution.

Comment: When you got rid of absolute value bars, you forgot to add that in the first case $x \ge 4$ and in the second case $x < 4$.

Comment: @Vasya: Not in this caes: the O.P. simply used that $|x-4|=\max(x-4, 4-x)$.

Comment: @Bernard: That's not what I see in the original post

Comment: @Vasya: To prove $\max(a,b)<c$, you just prove both $a<c$ **and** $b<c$.

Comment: @JohnWatson Your response is fine - having never done this kind of problem before, I should have used the definition of absolute value from the start - I was missing the extra constraints given by that definition (ie, x>16 as you mentioned).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: your inequality is equivalent to
$$-4-2x>3|x-4|$$
and you have two cases:
$$x\geq 4$$ and we get $$-4-2x>3(x-4)$$
or
$$x<4$$ and we get $$-4-2x>-3(x-4)$$

Comment: Great response, and this gets at the heart of what I was missing. The definition of absolute value requires separate solutions for $x \geq 4$ and $x < 4$. Continuing shows that for $x \geq 4$ we have $x< \frac{8}{5}$ as mentioned, but since that is not within the restriction $x \geq 4$, it is not part of the solution. Likewise for $x<4$.

Comment: Funny that of the 4 textbooks I use in my classroom, none of them mentions this rather important fact. Does anyone have a good resource recommendation that explains this well?

Comment: have i not explained this well?

Comment: see here http://www.analyzemath.com/Equations/Absolute_Value_Tutorial.html i hope this will help you

Comment: Your answer was definitely sufficient and was accepted. Thanks! I get a frustrated when my bachelor's in mathematics has holes in it, (though they are inevitable in any major) because available resources gloss over details in the interest of better "understanding." ie, educators often skip  depth in the interest of breadth - and one does not learn to swim well in the shallows.

Comment: Also, a high school student who doesn't really understand the definition of absolute value may not easily see why $|x-4|=...$ implies either $x \geq 4$ or $x < 4$ because this part is often glossed over in high school level textbooks; almost none of my algebra II students could tell me the definition of absolute value when they arrived, though most could solve absolute value equations and inequalities.

Comment: I made the resource I was looking for in the answer below. Yours was fine, but I wanted to clarify why we had two cases in the context of the definition of absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the absolute value of a real number (or expression) $z$ is

$$|z| =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  z  & \mbox{if } z \geq 0 \\
  -z & \mbox{if } z < 0
 \end{array}
\right.
$$

Solving the equation in the OP for the absolute value portion yields
$$ \left| x-4 \right| < \frac{4+2x}{-3}$$
Based on the definition of absolute value, $z$ is the "stuff" inside the absolute value bars: $z=x-4$. Applying the definition of aboslute value we have

$$|x-4| =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  x-4  & \mbox{if } x-4 \geq 0 \\
  -(x-4) & \mbox{if } x-4 < 0
 \end{array}
\right.
$$

From this we see that for $x-4$, $x \geq 4$ and for $-(x-4)$, $x<4$.

Adding these two constraints to the algebraically derived solutions in the OP explains why there are actually no solutions. Specifically, $x<\frac{8}{5}$ AND $x \geq 4$ is impossible - likewise for $x>16$ AND $x<4$.